# Can I make a section of a responsive WordPress site NOT responsive?

Tags: wordpress, responsive, mobile-website

I have a WordPress site that is fully responsive which I love-- but one of the pages is a list of songs that are in 2 columns. It looks really messed up on mobile devices so I was wondering if there are tags or something I can put around the code just for the songs so that only that section would NOT be responsive and just shrink in proportion with other devices. See screenshot. Sometimes I think non-responsive sites look better. This one is fine except for the Music page. I just don't like how the songs line up on mobile devices.

#### Responsive vs NonResponsive

[image: Responsive vs NonResponsive]

Answer (score 2):

First let me state that you should find an alternate/appropriate layout for them on mobile (such as single column, or click > popup in 2 column). The easiest thing to do would be to set a media query at the size they start to "look bad" and force it into a single column.

That said, you can conditionally load in a [Viewport Meta Tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) pretty easily using the [`wp_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) hook, or if your theme has a "per page" header/meta tag section, just add the meta tag in there. If it does not, something like the following in your `functions.php` file should work:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_custom_viewport_meta' );
function add_custom_viewport_meta(){
    if( get_the_ID() == 123 ){
        echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">';
    }
}
```

Of course, replace `123` with the actual ID of the page you want it displayed on, and replace `initial-scale=1` with whatever number gives you the desired appearance.

Comment: Thanks a million! Can you clarify this ", or click > popup in 2 column"   Would that be in code or is that a WordPress option?

Comment: It's something you'd have to code, unless there's a plugin out there to handle the audio platform you're using (I'm not sure if there is or what's even available). Here's a quick mockup of what I mean: https://i.imgur.com/4g5nWIN.png - it would take some significant set up, but it would allow you to keep the two columns and more _appropriately_ accommodate mobile devices. There may even be themes out there that are more geared toward audio clips and have something better built into them, unfortunately I couldn't recommend any of the top of my head

Answer (score 0):

I've found that setting width and height parameters to vmax and vmin respectively will make any page look the same on any screen size. What you would want to do is determine the height and width of the element in pixels on desktop and then divide the width properties (ie max-width) by your screen width and height properties by your screen height. It also takes care of if the user rotates their phone.